# How to run tkinter inside a docker container on MacBook Pro?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, docker, tkinter

I'm trying to run a python GUI application that uses `tkinter` module inside a docker container on my MacBook Pro.

So I installed [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/empowering-docker-using-tkinter-gui-bf076d9e4974) to run a simple tkinter program inside a docker container.

And here's the error message I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/tkinter_app.py", line 4, in <module>
    root_window = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.knFz0UzqxP/org.xquartz:0"
```

The value of my `DISPLAY` environment variable is `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.knFz0UzqxP/org.xquartz:0`.

Anyone knows how to solve this error?

Here's the Dockerfile in the tutorial

```
# Slim version of Python
FROM python:3.8.12-slim

# Download Package Information
RUN apt-get update -y

# Install Tkinter
RUN apt-get install tk -y

# Commands to run Tkinter application
CMD ["/app/tkinter_app.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Line 4 of `/app/tkinter_app.py` is `root_window = tk.Tk()`.

My MacOS version is `11.6.1`.

Comment: The easiest path is almost certainly going to be to run this application outside of Docker, maybe in a Python virtual environment.  It seems like your Dockerfile is missing the `COPY` lines that copy your application into the image, and the `ENTRYPOINT` split is odd; are either of these things causing problems?  How are you running the container?  Is the question related to your application source, or just running the application trying to wire the MacOS X server into the isolated container?

Comment: DISPLAY environment variable seems to be wrong, I have never seen a DISPLAY of this form.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just want to run the [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/empowering-docker-using-tkinter-gui-bf076d9e4974) correctly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you so much. Your code works successfully on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little docker image with `xeyes` in it to test X11 clients with the XQuartz X11 server on my Mac using this as my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Base Image
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache xeyes

# Set a working directory
WORKDIR /work

# Start a shell by default
CMD ["ash"]
```

And then I built it like this:

```
docker build -t setchell/xeyes .
```

And I run it with this:

```
# Prerequisites
#   brew cask install xquartz
    
# Set your Mac IP address
IP=$(/usr/sbin/ipconfig getifaddr en0)

# Allow connections from Mac to XQuartz
/opt/X11/bin/xhost + "$IP"

# Run container
docker run -it -e DISPLAY="${IP}:0" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix setchell/xeyes
```

And once in the container, I just run:

```
xeyes
```

And here is the result:

[image]

---

Note that I had to start XQuartz on my Mac, go to *"Preferences"* and then *"Security"* and tick (check) both options and restart my Mac before the above procedure. See diagram [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593701/2836621).

There may well be simpler ways, and some steps may be unnecessary and if anyone knows a simpler method, please ping me. I'm always happy to learn.

Comment: @Nimantha I would prefer the comment to remain as I am unsure if this is the best/simplest method and I would like to learn too if someone knows a better way. Also, it's only fair to warn users if I am not certain about my answer.

Comment: Noted. The issue with the last paragraph (removed in Revision 2) is that it could apply to any number of questions. One of the reasons that such content is removed in Stack Overflow is that it's assumed that it's implied. E.g. not saying "Hope this helps", or that last paragraph - all users should be happy to receive feedback on a better, simpler method and happy to learn new ways of doing things.