# XQuartz: Can't Open Display Mac OS

Tags: docker, macos, xquartz

While trying to follow [these SO instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70722222/how-to-run-tkinter-inside-a-docker-container-on-macbook-pro) for getting a simple Xeyes application running from within a Docker container on a Mac (10.15.5) using XQuartz, this is what I get:

$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY="${IP}:0" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix so_xeyes

/work # xeyes
Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.9:0

---

Here are the steps to reproduce:

$ `brew install --cask xquartz`

Dockerfile:

```
# Base Image
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache xeyes

# Set a working directory
WORKDIR /work

# Start a shell by default
CMD ["ash"]
```

Build image with:

$ `docker build -t so_xeyes .`

And run the Docker Container/xeyes with this:

```
# Set your Mac IP address
IP=$(/usr/sbin/ipconfig getifaddr en0)
echo $IP
192.168.1.9

# Allow connections from Mac to XQuartz
/opt/X11/bin/xhost + "$IP"
192.168.1.9 being added to access control list

# Run container
docker run -it -e DISPLAY="${IP}:0" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix so_xeyes
```

When inside the container, type:
`xeyes`

BUT, I get the following error:  `Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.9:0`

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this or to investigate further?

Comment: Can you run any X11 client natively on your Mac? I mean what happens if you run `xclock` or `xterm` on your Mac without docker?

Comment: Have you tried `-e DISPLAY=:0` ?

Comment: I think I started XQuartz and went to its *"Preferences"*, then *"Security"* and checked (i.e. ticked) both options and restarted the Mac then it worked. Let me know if that works and I'll update the linked answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I can run `xclock` and `xterm` on my Mac without docker.

Comment: @Philippe Using -e DISPLAY=:0 does not work.
```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix so_xeyes
/work # xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

Comment: I just checked this again. As long as I have both boxes ticked on the XQuartz *"Preferences"*->*"Security"* tab, and `DISPLAY=MYMACIPADDRESS:0` and I run `xhost +` on my Mac, then `xeyes` works from inside Docker.

Answer (score 5):

@MarkSetchell gave me a hint with suggesting I needed to modify the XQuartz *Preferences* > *Security*...

But, even after selecting "Allow connections from network clients", it still didn't work.

[image]

Then I found a Gist that gave me a little more information here because someone commented that after they made the change, they needed to reboot their Mac (again): https://gist.github.com/cschiewek/246a244ba23da8b9f0e7b11a68bf3285

So, after I made the change AND rebooted my Mac, it worked!

Thanks for guiding me to the final answer!

ALSO NOTE: You do NOT need to volume mount the .X11 directory for this to work:

`docker run -it -e DISPLAY="${IP}:0" so_xeyes`

Comment: I did actually mention restarting the Mac if you read my comment under your question

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Ahh, you're right!  Sorry I didn't see that earlier.  If you want to write up the steps as answer, I'll give you credit.

Comment: It's fine, don't fret

Answer (score 1):

By default, X11 does not listen over TCP/IP.  You can enable that if you want in Settings, but I don't think it's necessary here.  Docker should be able to route traffic to the unix domain socket setup by launchd for DISPLAY (eg: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jTIfZplv7A/org.xquartz:0).

If that doesn't work, you should reach out to Docker to add support for that as it's much preferred to using TCP for X11 traffic.

Comment: I think I got it working like this too. I'll check later.

Comment: Mmmm, I can't get this to work. Could you clarify how DISPLAY should be set exactly please? Saying *"don't override it"* from whatever it is doesn't say really say how it should be set. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia  According to the X.org site, X11 can listen over TCP/IP Network Connections.  https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.0/doc/html/Xserver.1.html 
"The X server supports client connections via a platform-dependent subset of the following transport types: TCP/IP, Unix Domain sockets, DECnet, and several varieties of SVR4 local connections. See the DISPLAY NAMES section of the X(7) manual page to learn how to specify which transport type clients should try to use."  Unless XQuartz doesn't follow the XServer protocol?

Comment: @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia  The X.org site goes on to explain: "TCP/IP

"The hostname part of the display name should be the server machine's IP address name. Full Internet names, abbreviated names, and IP addresses are all allowed. For example: x.org:0, expo:0, 198.112.45.11:0, bigmachine:1, and hydra:0.1." -https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.0/doc/html/X.7.html

Comment: @ScottFred Correct, if you are using TCP, the format of DISPLAY is <server address>:<display>[.<screen>].  To use the unix domain socket for that display (ie: locally), you would use DISPLAY=:<display>[.<screen>].  For XQuartz, you should not override the value of DISPLAY set by launchd.  You can see what that should be with `launchctl getenv DISPLAY`.  It will be something like /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jTIfZplv7A/org.xquartz:0